# Proof of similar vertex characteristics in two isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, graph-isomorphism

Prove the following:

1. If G≅H then G and H have the same maximum degree.
2. If G≅H then G and H have the same number of vertices of maximum degree.
3. If G≅H then there is an isomorphism of induced graphs on the vertices of maximum degree.

How do I prove (1) and (2) without just simply saying there exists a bijection between the two and by the definition of isomorphism and bijection, they are one-to-one?  I don't know what the professor is looking for here as far as a proof goes.  Would a contradiction of some sort be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

For (1) and (2), show that if $\phi:G\to H$ is an isomorphism, then $v$ and $\phi(v)$ have the same degree for all $v\in V(G)$.  Because $\phi$ must be a bijection on the vertex set, this implies that $G$ and $H$ have the same degree sequences.

Comment: So I've worked out the two sides of the proof and end up with something like (v)≤(ϕ(v)) and (ϕ(v))≤(v), so (v)=(ϕ(v)) for all vertices of G and H implying that the degree sequences of G and H are the same.  Would you say from a proof standpoint that it is sufficient to show that the degree sequences are the same and that it follows that 1, 2, and 3 are true.  Or is there a way I should prove them individually?